# Android: Animating a popup menu automatically

Tags: android, menu, popup

How can we set the timer  so that after completion of an  Image-view animation, a pop up menu should come from bottom automatically with out the user intervention.

Help is always appreciated......!

here is the code

```
        AnimationDrawable ekgframeAnimation4 =
         (AnimationDrawable) ekgimgview4.getBackground();



         if (ekgframeAnimation4.isRunning()) {
            ekgimgview4.postDelayed(ekgframeAnimation4, 60000);
            ekgframeAnimation4.stop();



            findViewById(R.id.ekgimgview4).postDelayed(new Runnable()
             { 
                 public void run()
                 { 
                     openOptionsMenu(); 
                 }
             }, 60000);


         }

         else {
            ekgframeAnimation4.stop();
           ekgframeAnimation4.start();
           ekgimgview4.postDelayed(ekgframeAnimation4, 60000);

           findViewById(R.id.ekgimgview4).postDelayed(new Runnable()
             { 
                 public void run()
                 { 
                     openOptionsMenu(); 
                 }
             }, 60000);


         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `View.postDelayed` call and in the Runnable call `openOptionsMenu`.

EDIT: if your animation lasts 1000 milliseconds and there is a View with the id `R.id.exampleview`, then something like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.exampleview).postDelayed(new Runnable()
{ 
    public void run()
    { 
        openOptionsMenu(); 
    }
}, 1000);
```

should do it. Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri  Thanks a lot man,my animation runs for 1 minute and after that the pop up menu should come, plz see the  code I posted with in which I should write the code for pop up menu

Comment: @Femi  thanks, but how can we do it  if  in case of a view flipper. I mean I have 3 views in a view flipper and in the third view I should deal with the above code. I tried a lot but its not working

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri  Hi, its not working for me. see the code which I posted

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't have `postDelayed` call. Immediately after you start the animation for 1 minute (60000 milliseconds) then call `postDelayed` with a 60000 delay.

Comment: @Femi  hmmm  now its working, but how to animate popup menu when the animation  ends automatically I dont know how to do this as I m new to android, plz see the code I posted. waiting 4 reply..!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that you can control the options menu animation.